# I wrote code that uses the LZW Algorithm, what are ways that could work or fail when running the program?

Tags: java, lzw

What are some ways when running the code that uses the LZW Algorithm for Compression/Decompression that would cause the code to fail and work?

Comment: That's a somewhat weird open-ended question. It could fail if it was implemented wrong and work if it was implemented right. Do you have a more specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JoachimSauer well, the program I wrote takes two parameters, one for the text file path and the second is the bit length. If I pass a really low bit length or a high bit length value will the LZW Algorithm still work?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried it? As it stands, the question is extremely vague.